# Netlogo set specific xycor

Tags: coordinates, netlogo

This is my first Netlogo script and I am a complete beginner and need help in setting the xy coordinates for my turtles which are boats. I wish the boats to be positioned across the top of the world (in a 30 x 30 world, with origin in the bottom left-hand corner). The number of boats is selected by a slider, ranging from 1 to 4. After looking at other questions & answers, I have tried the following code, but cannot get it to work, either "expected closing bracket" or "FOREACH expected at least 2 inputs, a list and an anonymous command" errors.

```
create-boats N-boats                 ;; create the boats
  [set color red                         ;; give them a color, a size and shape
    set size 1
    set shape "arrow"
    (foreach [ 0 1 2 3 ] [6 12 18 24] [28 28 28 28] [ xy -> boats [ setxy item 0 xy item 1 xy ] ] )
    set heading 180]]]
```

I also tried "set xcor one-of [6 12]", but sometimes get the boats lined up on top of each other, so I wish to specify the exact coordinates. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do they have to be equally spaced? Or just anywhere along the top? If anywhere along the top, you are better off choosing 4 random patches in that row and getting each of them to sprout a boat. Something like (not tested):

```
ask n-of N-boats patches with [pycor = max-pycor]
[ sprout 1
  [ set color red
    set heading 180
    set shape "arrow"
   ]
]
```

Just as a general newbie tip with NetLogo, if you are using `foreach` then you should immediately think about whether what you really want is some sort of agentset. It's particularly common for people coming from some other coding background to try and do things in `for` loops that are better handled as agentsets in NetLogo.

Comment: Thanks JenB, this works but I do want the boats equally spaced and that was the reason I tried to set coordinates.  I like the idea of using "sprout".

Comment: If you want evenly spaced then you either need a formula to turn the slide value (1 to 4) into locations from 0 to 30, or you need a select case type approach where you can say, if it's 1 then the positions are ...., if it's 2 then the positions are... etc

Comment: See below. You can use a list of locations, but in many cases the positions can be calculated.

Answer (score 1):

First, to answer your syntax issues:

Remember that the code in brackets after CREATE-TURTLES is run by a single turtle. After all the turtles are created, each turtle runs the code, one-at-a-time. It looks like you're trying to position all the turtles. That's probably not what you meant.

Second: look at the FOREACH.

```
( foreach [ 0 1 2 3 ] [6 12 18 24] [28 28 28 28] [ xy -> boats [ setxy item 0 xy item 1 xy ] ] )
```

- You've got the foreach in ( and ) -- that's good.
- You've got THREE separate lists as input -- that's fine, too, but looks like maybe you meant that to be one list? Not sure.
- Your anonymous procedure has only ONE input: xy. That's a problem, since you have THREE lists as input.
- You are referring to ITEM 0 and ITEM 1... which doesn't make a lot of sense at that point, unless you passed a list of lists, but no... still not.
- Finally, it looks like you meant to `ask boats` but if you did, since this is inside the create-turtles code block, this is already being excuted by a boat. So, this boat will ask all boats to do something. If this was otherwise correct, you'd just do the boat commands--you are essentially already inside an "ask".

So, this is not ideal, in any case. Let's start at the top.

## Three Ways to Set Turtle Location

If you want to put turtles at specific x and y coordinates, you have a few choices. Here's three:

- **Use Math** based on the value of WHO to calculate the coordinates.

  - (Or a counter, if you want to keep your model "who-agnostic")
- **Use a set of patches** (probably created using Math, too.) The patches `SPROUT` the turtles.
- **Use a List** of coordinates. Each turtle pulls its location from the list.

> #### A Note on the Examples.
>
> All the below examples focus on setting the position. After the boats
> are created, the boats are asked to run a procedure called
> `apply-boat-properties`, which is where things like color, heading,
> size, and other properties would be set. This is to remove clutter
> from the examples. It also makes it quite easy to find where the
> properties are being set.
>
> ```
> to apply-boat-properties
>   ;; run by a boat
>   set heading 180  
>   set shape "arrow"
>   set color gray
> end
> ```

### Math (aka "calculated position")

You can do this is the locations are in a pattern that can be calculated. This can be easy to do, but can also be hard and require a lot of tweaking and experimentation to get *just right*. The weird NetLogo world geometry can sometimes be confusing.

#### Simple Example of Calculated Positioning

```
to make-fleet [ #fleet-count ]
  create-boats #fleet-count
  [ setxy (min-pxcor + 6 + who * 6) max-pycor
    apply-boat-properties
  ]
```

#### Elaborate Example of Calculated Positioning

- Varies the gap between boats automatically.
- The boats are located without regard to patch centers,
  unless "$center-on-patches?" is set to true
- `WHO` is not used in the calculations. This ensures the math comes out right, even if other turtles already exist in the model.

```
to make-fleet [ $fleet-count $center-on-patches? ]
  ;; requires breed [ boats boat ]
  set-default-shape boats "arrow" 
  let $boat-size 1
  ;; this is the real "0" in terms of even positioning
  let $far-left-edge-xcor min-pxcor - 0.5
  let $total-width-of-all-boats ($boat-size * $fleet-count)
  let $gap-between-boat-edges (world-width - $total-width-of-all-boats) / ($fleet-count + 1)
  let $gap-between-boat-centers $gap-between-boat-edges + $boat-size
  let $gap-between-left-edge-and-first-boat-center $gap-between-boat-edges + ($boat-size / 2)
  ;; I use boat-number, rather than who,
  ;;so this procedure will work even if there are other turtles
  let $boat-number 0 ;; 0 to (#fleet-count - 1) 
  create-boats $fleet-count
  [ let $x 0
    if-else ( $center-on-patches? )
    [ set $x min-pxcor
           + floor ( $gap-between-left-edge-and-first-boat-center )
           + ceiling ( $boat-number * $gap-between-boat-centers )
    ]
    [ ;; position without regard to patch alignment
      set $x $far-left-edge-xcor
           + $gap-between-left-edge-and-first-boat-center
           + $boat-number * $gap-between-boat-centers
    ]
    let $y max-pycor
    setxy $x $y
    set $boat-number $boat-number + 1
  ]
  ask boats [ apply-boat-properties ] 
end
```

### Using a Set of Patches

This is a lot like the previous method, but we create a set of patches, then ask the patches to make the turtles. This is useful for creating a set of turtles on a specific area of the world, like on an edge, or in a specific pattern of patches, or filling an area with a randomly scattered set of turtles.

```
to make-fleet [ $boat-gap ]
  let $locations patches with
  [
    ;; rules to find the patches
    pycor = max-pycor ;; top row
    and
    (pxcor - min-pxcor) mod $boat-gap = 0
  ]
  ask $locations [ sprout 1 [ set breed boats ] ]
  ask boats [ apply-boat-properties ]
end
```

### Using A List of Coordinates

If the required coordinates are few, or are can't be calculated, you can put the coordinates in a list. The created turtles can pull the coordinates from the list.

```
to make-fleet [ $fleet-count ]
  ;; A list of x y coordinate pairs.
  ;; The coordinate pairs are also in a list
  let $coordinates
  [
    ;  x   y ;
    [  6   0 ]
    [ 12   0 ]
    [ 18   0 ]
    [ 24   0 ]
  ]
  ;; initialize the counter uses as the list index
  let $boat-number 0
  ;; make boats
  create-boats $fleet-count
  [ ;; get the coordinate pair
    let $xy item $boat-number $coordinates
    ;; get the x and y from the pair
    let $x first $xy ;; aka item 0 $xy
    let $y last  $xy ;; aka item 1 $xy
    ;; apply the coordinate
    setxy $x $y
    ;; increment the index number
    set $boat-number $boat-number + 1
  ]
  ask boats [ apply-boat-properties ]
```

Note that the above will make errors if `$fleet-count` is more than 4, because the coordinate list has only 4 items.

You could use `FOREACH` on the list, and create 1 turtle for each coordinate. This is handy when a large list of coordinates have been read from a file.

```
to make-fleet [ $coordinates ]
  ;; assume $coordinates is a list of pairs of coordinates.
  ;; like [ [ 1 2 ] [ 3 4 ] [ 5 6 ] ]
  ;; we are going to ask the patch at each of the coordinates
  ;; to create a turtle. Then we will set up the turtle.
  ( foreach $coordinates
    [ [ $xy ] ->
      ask patch first $xy last $xy
      [ sprout 1 [ set breed boats ] ]
    ] 
  )
  ask boats [ apply-boat-properties ]
end
```

### Finally

There are other ways, too, and many other formulas for calculated positions.

Comment: Thank you so much TurtleZero!! Will try your suggestions and let you know which works best for my model. really appreciate your time and suggestions.

Comment: Hi TurtleZero, the option of using a set of patches was just perfect, so thanks again.